# Joblib parallelized code fails to update global variable

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, global-variables, joblib

So let's say I want to evaluate the average vector out of a bunch of *n* vectors whose entries are defined via a random function. To evaluate the average of thes vectors I would add them up every time a new one is created and finally I would divide all by *n*, like I did here (where I call *n*=`avg_iterations`):

```
iterations=1000   # iterations I do to fill a single vector
avg_iterations=10 # how many single vectors I generate
N=5
avg_vector=np.zeros(N)
def vector_generator(M):
    vector=np.zeros(M)
    global avg_vector
    for i in range(iterations):
        k=int(M * random())
        vector[k]+=1
    avg_vector=avg_vector+vector
    print(avg_vector)

for i in range(avg_iterations):
    vector_generator(N)

avg_vector=avg_vector/avg_iterations
print("final vector:")
print(avg_vector)
```

I am satisfied with the result of this, but I would like to parallelize it. I am trying to do this with `joblib`. Here is my failed attempt (the code changes only from the main for loop):

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(vector_generator)(N) for i in range(avg_iterations))

avg_vector=avg_vector/avg_iterations
print("final vector:")
print(avg_vector)
```

The output I get is embarassing:

```
[217. 177. 211. 207. 188.]
[217. 177. 211. 207. 188.]
..........................
[217. 177. 211. 207. 188.]
final vector:
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Looks like it is able to update the value of `avg_vector` just once, then it stays the same, in the end it is re-initialized to zero. Yet `avg_vector` should be accessible and editable everywhere in the code. I know this problem is related to parallelization, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.